# Android Phone Gap Throws Error on Creating a project

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to Install Android and Phone Gap. When i try to create a android project using Phone Gap command prompt `C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby bin/droidgap create "C:/Users/sureshn/Desktop/Ph
oneGap/Android/PhoneGapAndroid/phonegap-phonegap-android-ab8950a/SureshWorld`
I get the following error

```
"C:/Users/sureshn/Desktop/PhoneGap/Android/PhoneGapAndroid/phonegap-phonegap-andr
oid-ab8950a/lib/create.rb:24:in ``': No such file or directory - android-sdk-pat
h.bat android.bat (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Users/sureshn/Desktop/PhoneGap/Android/PhoneGapAndroid/phonegap-
phonegap-android-ab8950a/lib/create.rb:24:in `guess_paths'
        from C:/Users/sureshn/Desktop/PhoneGap/Android/PhoneGapAndroid/phonegap-
phonegap-android-ab8950a/lib/create.rb:7:in `initialize'
        from bin/droidgap:24:in `new'
        from bin/droidgap:24:in `<main>'"
```

My Path is set to

```
C:/Ruby192/bin;
C:/Users/sureshn/Desktop/PhoneGap/Android/Apache Ant/apache-ant-1.8.1/bin;
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_23/bin;
C:/Users/sureshn/Desktop/PhoneGap/Android/AndroidSDK/android-sdk-windows/tools;
C:/Users/sureshn/Desktop/PhoneGap/Android/PhoneGapAndroid/phonegap-phonegap-android-ab8950a/bin;
```

I have also set the `ANDROID_HOME`, `ANT_HOME`, `JAVA_HOME` variables. 
Can the gurus throw me the light where i am doing wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: what happens when you just run "android-sdk-path.bat" from the command line?

Comment: Fixed the issue. Once you install all the necessary software for android enviornment, follow this path to create the project http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1915